# dapper.contrib postres 42P01 error: relation "<table name>" does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, dapper-contrib

Using dapper.contrib, I keep getting the error: `'42P01: relation "tblproduct" does not exist'`.

I believe this to be because postgresql is case sensitive. The entity itself has the schema annotation of `'[Table("tblProduct")]'`.

I can't find why the generated sql will use a lowercase tablename? I'm using the `'SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper'` to force the case but this doesn't work either. Am I missing something? Thanks

```
    public ICollection<Product> GetAll(int count)
    {
        if (SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper != null)
            return null;

        SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) =>
        {
            return "tblProduct";
        };

        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.GetAll<Product>().Take(count).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this: I believe dapper.contrib sets all table/column names to lowercase. I've not found a way to force it to use any other case. Will try dapper extensions instead

Answer (score 1):

You can see what Dapper is generating with :

```
NpgsqlLogManager.Provider = new ConsoleLoggingProvider(NpgsqlLogLevel.Trace, true, true);
```

I fixed my problem on PostgresSQL with qutoes :

```
SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => $"\"{type.Name}s\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table name in the database is the plural form of the class name, you can use this

```cs
SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => $"\"{Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(type.Name)}\"";
```